# Type Error: can join an iterable of bytes

Tags: ironpython, xlrd

I am new to Python programming.  Using IronPython 2.7.1, intend to import data from excel using python.  Using xlrd pacakage to import.

I have only these two lines in my file

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
book =  open_workbook('test.xls')
```

This returns an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readExcel.py", line 3, in 
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7.1\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.
py", line 432, in open_workbook
TypeError: can only join an iterable of bytes

Can somebody tell a remedy to this error?